# Why didn't Ingrid grow up in Storybrooke but Henry did?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

I was watching "*Shattered Sight*" in season 4 again, and I realized something. When Emma asks Ingrid the reason she didn't grow up, she said that no one grows up in Storybrooke.

But Ingrid was not cursed, just like Henry. So why did Henry grow up and she didn't?

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell, [Henry](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Henry_Mills) is the only one who aged in Storybrooke during the first curse.

> Henry is also frustrated by the sameness in town, and believes he doesn't belong.

I don't know if by sameness they mean "it seems like nothing in the town ever changes, I mean, even the pregnant woman never seems to give birth."

One would think Henry would notice that none of his classmates aged, and he advanced in school while the others didn't, but maybe he is just slow. As in slow witted...

> For twenty-eight years, Ashley remains pregnant until Emma arrives in Storybrooke, to which the curse begins to weaken and time starts to move forward [giving birth to [Alexandra](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Alexandra)]

**I can't find anything definitive. But I would wager because she comes from a land of magic, the anti-aging properties of Storybrooke work for her as well as the rest of the *imported* townspeople.**

People outside of Storybrooke age at the regular rate, including Emma, Neil, and August.

Answer (score 1):

Ingrid may not have been cursed directly like the others but she was born in the magic world and I think the curse works on those from there even if they came through other means; like Storybrooke itself is cursed. Emma and Pinocchio were unaffected because the curse only works in Storybrooke and Henry was unaffected because he was born in this world.